# Why do numpy's polyfit and polyval expect polynomial coefficients in opposite order?

Tags: python, numpy

I used numpy's `polyfit` to fit some noisy data and then wanted to use `polyval` to evaluate the fit at some new points. For some reason, fitting works fine but `polyval` only gives correct results when I reverse the order of the coefficients of the polynomial:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# a noisy line
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = x + np.random.normal(0, 1, x.shape)

# calculate fit polynomial
fit_coeffs_poly = poly.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)
fit_polynomial_poly = poly.Polynomial(fit_coeffs_poly)(x)

# plot to check fit 
plt.plot(x, y, label='noisy')
plt.plot(x, fit_polynomial_poly, '-r', label='polyfit')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

The fit looks good:

[image]

`polyval` only works when the coefficients are reversed:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 10):
>>>    print(np.polyval(fit_coeffs_poly, i))

0.9792056688016727
1.139755470535941
1.3003052722702093
1.4608550740044774
1.6214048757387456
1.781954677473014
1.9425044792072823
2.1030542809415502
2.2636040826758186
2.424153884410087

>>> for i in range(0, 10):
>>>    print(np.polyval(fit_coeffs_poly[::-1], i))

0.16054980173426825
1.139755470535941
2.1189611393376135
3.0981668081392866
4.077372476940959
5.056578145742631
6.035783814544304
7.0149894833459765
7.9941951521476495
8.973400820949323
```

I can't help but feel like this is wrong somehow, it doesn't make sense for them to be backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug around **a lot** and found out what was going on. It turns out numpy has two sets of polynomial tools, one in the base numpy library, and another in `numpy.polynomial` and they expect things in opposite order. Both `polyfit` and `polyval` are found in both libraries and appear to operate the same on this simple case, but their parameters are different:

From `numpy`:

```
def polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)
def polyval(p, x)
```

Both `polyfit` and `polyval` expect and return polynomial coefficients ordered from **high to low** degree.

From `numpy.polynomial`:

```
def polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None)
def polyval(x, c, tensor=True)
```

Both `polyfit` and `polyval` expect and return polynomial coefficients ordered from **low to high** degree. Also note that `polyval` expects parameters in a different order.

Here's a quick demo:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# a noisy line
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = x + np.random.normal(0, 1, x.shape)

# calculate fit polynomial with base numpy
fit_coeffs_np = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)
fit_polynomial_np = poly.Polynomial(fit_coeffs_np[::-1])(x)
print("numpy", fit_coeffs_np)

# calculate fit polynomial with numpy.polynomial.polynomial
fit_coeffs_poly = poly.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)
fit_polynomial_poly = poly.Polynomial(fit_coeffs_poly)(x)
print("poly", fit_coeffs_poly)

# test some values
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(np.polyval(fit_coeffs_np, i), poly.polyval(i, fit_coeffs_poly))

# make a nice plot
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.plot(x, y, label='noisy')
plt.plot(x, fit_polynomial_poly, '-g', label='np.poly')
plt.plot(x, fit_polynomial_np, '-r', label='np')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.text(0, 10, 'np: {}'.format(fit_coeffs_np))
plt.text(0, 9, 'np.poly: {}'.format(fit_coeffs_poly))
plt.savefig('good.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
-0.009244843991578149 -0.009244843991576678
1.0080792020754397 1.0080792020754408
2.0254032481424575 2.025403248142458
3.042727294209475 3.0427272942094756
4.060051340276494 4.060051340276493
5.077375386343512 5.07737538634351
6.094699432410529 6.094699432410528
7.112023478477547 7.112023478477545
8.129347524544565 8.129347524544563
9.146671570611582 9.14667157061158
```

The two appear to be nominally equivalent, but you can't mix and match without being aware of the slight differences.

If anyone is aware of **why** there are two different implementations, I would love to know.